# Number of ways distribute 12 identical action figures to 5 children

Tags: discrete-mathematics, power-series

Need a little help with this problem.

Use generating functions to determine the number of different ways 12 identical action figures can be given to five children so that each child receives at most three action figures.

So far I have that we are looking for the coefficient of $x^{12}$ and the generating function is $G(x) = (1 + x + x^2 + x^3)^{5}$ so this is equal to the form $G(x) = 1/(1-x)^n$ which is equal to $(1-x)^{-n}$ and then I'm trying to use the formula $C(n+k-1,k)x^k$ and using $k=12$ and $n=5$ to come out with $C(16,12)$ but I'm not sure if that is correct.

I don't know if I'm doing this correctly or messing up a step along the way. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no way to distribute 12 things to 5 kids that will not cause problems.

Comment: thank you, that made me chuckle, but alas this problem does not take into consideration hurt feelings.

Comment: I believe a generalization of this is answered in http://math.stackexchange.com/q/89417/139123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $\displaystyle G(x)=(1+x+x^2+x^3)^5=\big(\frac{1-x^4}{1-x}\big)^5=(1-x^4)^5(1-x)^{-5}$

$\displaystyle=\big(1-5x^4+\binom{5}{2}x^8-\binom{5}{3}x^{12}+\cdots\big)\big(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{k+4}{4}x^4\big)$,

so now you just have to find the coefficient of $x^{12}$ in this expression.

Comment: Thank you, I see where I made my mistake by using an infinte series rather than the correct series going to n