# How to expand $(1 - x)^{-5}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, generating-functions

How can I expand $(1 - x)^{-5}$ ?

---

There are different approaches given, but I am not getting exactly.

Comment: Can you please name the approaches that have been mentioned? It will be easy for us then to make you understand what is necessary.

Comment: Use newton binomial theorem for negative index , you can see it at wikipedia

Comment: @SchrodingersCat This one uses some formula which is different from my book's forrmula. Can you please help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875223/number-of-ways-distribute-12-identical-action-figures-to-5-children

Comment: @Garrick exactly what help do you want? please tell me what is the thing that is actually causing the confusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) to expand $(1-x)^{-5}$.
$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^{\beta+1}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{k+\beta \choose k}z^k.$$