# Distribute $n$ identical presents to $k$ children so that each child receives at most $3$ presents

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

I know that to distribute n identical presents to k children so that each child gets at least one is $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ and that to distribute n presents to $k$ children is $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$, and I understand why. In order for each child to get at least $2$ presents is $\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}$. However I have no clue how to make it so a child doesn't receive more than a certain number. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Im thinking its [number of ways to distribute presents to children with no restriction] - [number of ways to distribute presents to children such that at least 1 child gets 4+ presents]

Comment: I'd go with your #no restrictions - #at least one child gets at least 4 presents.  Are you having difficulty determining how to count the "bad" cases that you're subtracting off?

Comment: You need to use an [inclusion-exclusion argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). For a concrete example see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203835/enumerating-number-of-solutions-to-an-equation) and its answers; for the general result see [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146477/how-can-i-determine-the-number-of-unique-hands-of-size-h-for-a-given-deck-of-car).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number of ways to put $n$ unlabeled balls in $k$ bins with a max of $m$ balls in each bin](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89417/number-of-ways-to-put-n-unlabeled-balls-in-k-bins-with-a-max-of-m-balls-in)