$n$ identical balls are placed into $k$ distinct buckets, each bucket has at least $1$ ball and at most $m$ balls. How many ways?
I solved the problem using Python language and dynamic programming algorithm, What is the mathematical solution to this problem?
# Given n balls, k buckets, and m is a limit
n = 8
k = 6
m = 2

# The number of ways to place j balls into the first i buckets,
# where the number of balls placed in each bucket, denoted by 'a', satisfies the condition 1 <= a <= m
dp = [ [0 for i in range(n+1)] for j in range(k+1)]


# The bucket numbering starts from 1. Here, we are initializing the first bucket
for j in range(1,m+1):
    dp[1][j] = 1

for i in range(2,k+1):
    for j in range(i,min(m*i,n)+1):
        for z in range(1,m+1):
            if j-z>=i-1:
                dp[i][j] += dp[i-1][j-z]
            else:
                break

print(dp[k][n])


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Thank you very much, I'll go check it right away

Check this one as well because you need to combine both the ideas to get the answer. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89417/number-of-ways-to-put-n-unlabeled-balls-in-k-bins-with-a-max-of-m-balls-in

Taking help from this post, Stars and Bars method and extending the question to having at least p balls and at most m balls
this is what you need
$$\sum_{i=0}^r (-1)^i {k\choose i} {{n-k(p-1)-1-i(m-p+1)}\choose{k-1}}$$
where $r = {\left \lfloor {\frac{n-kp}{m-p+1}} \right \rfloor}$

Wow, Thank you very much!!!
